# "require/ export" is not defined in react api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm learning React and ES6. I used Webpack and Babel, and on my localhost my app works fine. But I don't know how to display it in the Internet. I have err: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined. 
I used 'script type="text/babel"...' and 'script type="text/jsx"...' but it doesn't help. My HTML app looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Movie List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My favourite movie list!-test</h1>
    <h3>REST API</h3><hr/>
    <main id="app"></main>
    <script type="text/babel" src="index.jsx"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="Movie.jsx"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="MovieInfo.jsx"></script>
    <script type="text/jsx" src="MovieList.jsx"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="MyButton.jsx"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="Thumb.jsx"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Previously I had:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title>Movie List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My favourite movie list!</h1>
        <h3>REST API</h3><hr/>
        <main id="app"></main>
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is example of my component:

```
import React from 'react';

var thumbStyle = {
    paddingLeft: '0',
    width: '20%',
    display: 'inline-block',
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
    marginTop: 0,
    float: 'left'
};
var imgStyle = {
    width: '100%'
};

export default class Thumb extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div style={thumbStyle}>
                <img 
                    src={this.props.src}
                    style={imgStyle} 
                    role="poster"
                    alt="poster"
                />
            </div>

        );
    }
}

Thumb.propTypes = {
    src: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

EDIT: I found solution. The problem was with bundle.js. It was not built properly before I displaied it on a server.

Firstly I had to build bundle.js using Webpack, then sent it to server. Now it works fine.

Comment: There are already questions answering how to deploy React code, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37152773/best-way-to-build-compile-deploy-reactjs-to-production

Comment: I'm afraid you misunderstood me. On my production server my app works fine. But I don't know how to display it in the Internet (not on localhost)

Comment: @TBlock I think the problem is in your debug mode..